# How to increment mysql data after a fixed time slot automatically?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I am creating a student management system and I want to increase the student standard after every year. If student is admitted in 1st standard then next year he would be in 2nd after that 3rd and so on.. Please help!

Comment: This question is both too broad and unclear and did not show any effort. There are a few ways to do this btw and you've been given a few.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`MySQL EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) like

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    DO
      UPDATE `student`  SET `standard` = `standard` + 1
      WHERE some_ID_Column = value;
```

Comment: Nice solution. Didn't know about it.

Comment: a `WHERE` clause would probably be needed here. Otherwise, that will update their entire database, if that's what they want.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes make sense but this is specimen answer considering OP haven't provided any information

Comment: @Rahul Wishing you luck on getting a green tick here. OP doesn't seem to know how Stack rolls ;-) I've kindly gave them a nudge in another of their question, so time will only tell.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a cron job that runs nightly and run a stored procedure that checks if the students have reached the condition for the next standard and if they have update the records.